# What's a difference between a KTable obtained by KStream.toTable() and KTable materialized directly from Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is any difference between the the two following approaches of obtaining a KTable?

Option 1:

```java
var kstream = streamsBuilder.stream(topicName, Consumed.with(...));
var mappedKTable = kstream.toTable(...);
```

Option 2:

```java
var nativeKTable = streamsBuilder.toTable(topicName, Consumed.with(...));
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what your question is to me. -- It's seems to be kinda semantic question. What does you data represent? Maybe this 4-part blog series helps: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-tables-part-1-event-streaming

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a topic you read it in as a stream. If you need it as a table because you only want the most recent value for each key you can use `.toTable()`. This is equivalent to reading a table.

If you read a stream then you might preform an aggregation which inherently converts into a KTable.

say you have a topic with the following contents

```
K1: 1
K1: 2
K2: 1
```

Reading this as a KTable will give you:

```
K1: 2
K2: 1
```

If you were to read as a KStream and preforming a sum aggregation will result in the following Ktable

```
K1:3
K2:1
```